# A strange problem with SELECT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, aws-aurora

I have a query that produces zeros when it shouldn't:

```
mysql> select 
     >   count(game_action_id) ga_count,
     >   count(distinct(game_action_id)) count_distinct,
     >   count(case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end) wager_count,
     >   count(distinct(case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end)) wager_count_distinct 
     > from game_action 
     > where created_timestamp >= '2020-11-01 00:00:00' 
     >   and created_timestamp <= '2020-11-01 23:59:59';
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ga_count | count_distinct | wager_count | wager_count_distinct |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  1980518 |        1980518 |     1746164 |                    0 |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (33.90 sec)
```

This is clearly linked to the fact that `count(distinct(case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end))` returns `NULL` when `type != 'WAGER'`:

```
mysql> select 
     >   count(game_action_id) ga_count,
     >   count(distinct(game_action_id)) count_distinct,
     >   count(case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end) wager_count,
     >   count(distinct(case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id else 1 end)) wager_count_distinct 
     > from game_action 
     > where created_timestamp >= '2020-11-01 00:00:00' 
     >   and created_timestamp <= '2020-11-01 23:59:59';
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ga_count | count_distinct | wager_count | wager_count_distinct |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  1980518 |        1980518 |     1746164 |              1746165 |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (33.90 sec)
```

On the other hand, the only difference between `wager_count` and `wager_count_distinct` is the use of `distinct`; is this a known error in 5.6?

***Edit 1***

In reply to a comment - the values I'm summing over:

```
mysql> select 
     >   game_action_id,
     >   game_action_id, 
     >   case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end, 
     >   case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id end 
     > from game_action 
     > where created_timestamp >= '2020-11-01 00:00:00' 
     >   and created_timestamp <= '2020-11-01 23:59:59';
...
|      375414452 |      375414452 |                                      375414452 |                                      375414452 |
|      375414453 |      375414453 |                                      375414453 |                                      375414453 |
|      375414454 |      375414454 |                                           NULL |                                           NULL |
|      375414455 |      375414455 |                                      375414455 |                                      375414455 |
|      375414455 |      375414455 |                                      375414455 |                                      375414455 |
...
```

Excerpt from a very long output list.

***Edit 2***

I've found a work-around, which will have to do for now. I was trying to find a smallest dataset that displayed this error, so I extracted the offending date interval from the table into a separate table with exactly the same configuration (partitions and indexes), and ran the query against that - and the error was gone! Inspired by this, I tried the following:

```
mysql> select
    ->   count(ga1.game_action_id) ga_count,
    ->   count(distinct(ga1.game_action_id)) count_distinct,
    ->   count(case when ga1.type='WAGER' then ga1.game_action_id end) wager_count,
    ->   count(distinct(case when ga1.type='WAGER' then ga1.game_action_id end)) wager_count_distinct
    -> from (
    ->   select * from game_action ga2
    ->   where ga2.created_timestamp >= '2020-11-01 00:00:00'
    ->     and ga2.created_timestamp <= '2020-11-01 23:59:59'
    -> ) ga1;
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ga_count | count_distinct | wager_count | wager_count_distinct |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
|  1980518 |        1980518 |     1746164 |              1746164 |
+----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (1 min 35.88 sec)
```

and it works! In fact, running against the entire table works too:

```
mysql> select
    ->   count(ga1.game_action_id) ga_count,
    ->   count(distinct(ga1.game_action_id)) count_distinct,
    ->   count(case when ga1.type='WAGER' then ga1.game_action_id end) wager_count,
    ->   count(distinct(case when ga1.type='WAGER' then ga1.game_action_id end)) wager_count_distinct
    -> from game_action ga1;
+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ga_count  | count_distinct | wager_count | wager_count_distinct |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 449043720 |      449043720 |   391849422 |            391849422 |
+-----------+----------------+-------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (14 min 0.70 sec)
```

My conclusion is that there must be something about the combination of `count(distinct(case ...))` with this `where` clause, which can screw things up internally in mysql.

Comment: Can you show us the values of a row with `type='WAGER'`?

Comment: Looks like a bug anyway.

Comment: Please add column names and the `type` column in the output. 5 rows are enough

Comment: Things to try: 1.remove the parenthesis after the `distinct`: `count(distinct case ... end)`. DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: 2. Add explicit `ELSE NULL` in your case: `case when type='WAGER' then game_action_id else null end`

Comment: I don't expect the above to work but it doesn't hurt. In any case, send a bug report to MySQL or AWS (or both). It looks like a bug due to some optimization or a corrupted index.

Comment: It would also help here if you added the table CREATE TABLE statement in the question. Is `game_action_id` nullable or not? Is it the primary key? Do all rows with `type='WAGER'` have `NULL` value in `game_action_id`? etc. These (and possibly other questions) would help others answer.

Comment: Please provide a small test case  -- fewer columns, less than 10 rows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known bug that multiple people have encountered inconsistently on AWS with MySQL. Here's the open [Bug Report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81031) you can contribute to.

Comment: I think it is a different problem, but similar; my query doesn't involve any indexes - `explain` says it is `SIMPLE`.

Comment: Yes upon further research, for that version of MySQL, people intermittently experience it with and without indexes.

Comment: That bug report refers to a problem with "index merge intersect", which does not seem to be relevant to the OP's query.